# How to get the real request in unit tests in Pyramid

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid framework for my application. I'm writing unit tests (tests.py file), where I want to:

1. get the actual request instead of dummyRequest and
2. also want to get the values of variables defined in config (development.ini) file.

I have gone through [How to get an actual Pyramid request when unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484061/how-to-get-an-actual-pyramid-request-when-unit-testing) question as well, but didn't get much from it.

Let me know how above can be achieved.

Comment: just create a request that your vie accepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first "want", you can see this well-written SO post:
[How to get an actual Pyramid request when unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484061/how-to-get-an-actual-pyramid-request-when-unit-testing)

It suggests to utilize the `DummyRequest`. "The thing to realize whenever you are unit testing (which is different from functional tests) is that you are testing a small 'unit'. This unit does not require a 'real' request, nor does it require a fully working system."

---

For your second "want", you can refer to the (1) Pyramid docs and (2) an SO post:

1. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting
2. [how can i get the ini data in pyramid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893628/how-can-i-get-the-ini-data-in-pyramid)

Essentially, in your view function, you can use `request.registry.settings` or `pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_registry().settings`, it behaves like a dictionary.

Comment: +1 Thanks! but I am not getting anything in pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_registry().settings(Returning as None). Please let me know if it is as expected or I am missing something. In case if it is 'None', then how to access the values defined in .ini file.

Comment: Have you indicated the settings file to use? You can take a look at line 15 of this Gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/sontek/1420255#file-gistfile1-py-L15